# How to open a modal in bootstrap if this is loaded via ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am calling a div where the modal is via Ajax. Once the div and its modal has been loaded, the button won't open the modal. The code below is the modal structure, it is just a [plain modal from bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals), and this has been loaded via ajax:

```
<div class="ajax-loaded-item">
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="myModalZ">Large modal</button>

 <div class="modal fade" id="myModalZ" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabelZ" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h2 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabelS">Filter our work</h2>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Content.....
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

If it is the case that I need to reload bootstrap.js where the modal jQuery is as the content is now loaded via ajax, is there a sort of `init` modal call I can do after my own ajax callback?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the jQuery to open the modal:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[data-target="myModalZ"]').click(function(){
        $('#myModalZ').modal('show');
    });
});
```

[More Documentation is here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

**EDITED:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('button[data-target="myModalZ"]').click(function(){
        if($('#myModalZ').length){
           $('#myModalZ').modal('show');
        } else {
           alert('Your message');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: let me give it a try, ye I did see the docs, even linked them in my question

Comment: Ok bingo. it works, thanks. I had to target the button via jQuery once ajax loaded.

Comment: @rob.m its great that my solution is working for you. happy to help you. Mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: will do as soon as it let me to

Comment: @CodeLღver It is possible that modal html might not be available when document is ready. So in this case this wont work.

Comment: At the time of document will load the modal html will not be there. after call of ajax the modal html will be present. In that case you can handle it.

Comment: What makes it work in my case is that I am doing what you have in your answer after my own ajax callback. What i did wrong when I tried to do this myself, was that I wasn't actually targeting the button, a little mistake that your answer actually brought to light ;)

Comment: @CodeLღver : yes that better though!

Comment: @rob.m check the updated answer. this will handle if the modal not loaded.

Answer (score 0):

First append received content inside body somewhere. Then trigger modal manually.

```
$.ajax(
    {
        url: "http://www.example.com/someAPI", 
        success: function(result){
            // Append content somewhere

            // Init button click event once your content is ready
            $('button[data-target="myModalZ"]').click(function(){
                $('#myModalZ').modal('show');
            });

    }
});
```

Please check out [full documentation here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals).

Comment: yeah but will open it auto, maybe I do need to call it with a click as the answer above suggests

Answer (score 0):

**As of Bootstrap v5.0+** they have changed the way that you launch a modal from JavaScript (see [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript)).

Now, in order to launch the modal the syntax is as follows:

```
const modal = new bootstrap.Modal('#myModal', options);
modal.show();
```

On that same [page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/#via-javascript), it explains what the optional 'options' argument can be.