# jQuery Ajax loads the html data fine but the attribute seemed 'unreadable'

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Please help me before I go crazy.
Okay, so I've been struggling with my code for a week and I still don't know what's not working.

I can call a modal using the data-target attribute of an anchor tag. I know it's working fine. Here is my PHP file. No problems with this also.

**PHP (placement-load.php)**

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_personal";
$r = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$nr = mysqli_num_rows($r);
if($nr > 0) {
    while($dt = mysqli_fetch_array($r)){
        echo "
            <tr>
                <td>".$dt[0]."</td>
                <td><a data-target='#modalShowDetails'>Edit</a></td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }
}else {
    echo "";
}
?>
```

I have two scenarios
If I did this:

```
<div class="table">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="placement-table">
            <?php include 'placement-load.php'; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

The table body will load just fine and if I click the Edit (in the anchor tag), the modal will load also.

BUT!

If I remove the include in the tbody tag and did this (using jQuery Ajax):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    autoRefresh();
});
function autoRefresh() {
    $.ajax( {
        method: 'POST',
        url: "php/placement-load.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#placement-table').html(data);
        }
    });
}
```

The table body will also load just fine but if I click the Edit (in the anchor tag), the modal won't work.

Why?

Comment: My guess is that using the ajax method the event listeners for `edit` are already in place and the ajax is pulling in the new content too late for them to be assigned with the function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open a modal in bootstrap if this is loaded via ajax?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28495266/how-to-open-a-modal-in-bootstrap-if-this-is-loaded-via-ajax)

Comment: where is the edit button?

Comment: @Mir in the php file `<a data-target='#modalShowDetails'>Edit</a>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it. I inserted `$.getScript("location of my script to open the modal here");` right below the `$('#placement-table').html(data)` in my autoRefresh function. Any thoughts on this?

Source: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

Answer (score 0):

As you are loading the data via ajax thats why the earlier jquery which already got bound with the html present in the DOM is not working on new html elements added to the DOM.

In such cases we are required to execute the jQuery already executed on the page once again to bind them with the newly added html as well.

The approach I take is just create a function called bind and add all the jQuery events which are not working anymore in it and call it on document's ready event and call that function on the completion of your ajax call as well.See the following snippet for reference:

```
function autoRefresh() {
    $.ajax( {
        method: 'POST',
        url: "php/placement-load.php",
        success: function(data) {
            $('#placement-table').html(data);
            bind(); //Calling bind function on ajax call success
        }
    });
}

//Define bind function
function bind(){
    //Add code to open the modal here
    //You can add all the jquery code which is not executing after loading the data from ajax
}

//calling bind() along with your autoRefresh function
$(document).ready(function() {
    autoRefresh();
    bind();
});
```